# What should I use between FDQuery, FDMemtable, and ClientDataset in Delphi FireDac?

Tags: delphi, firedac

New to Delphi. I'm developing an application that needs to access a MSSQL database, to do this I've used an FDConnection, FDQuery and a DataSource component connected to a grid. With these I can access/modify/delete data just fine. Now if for example I want to filter the grid, I can do this by changing the FDQuery component at run-time, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

I've thought about using something that stores tables in memory like ClientDatasets because I'm not sure if FDQuery does this, so that I can manage data I've already retrieved without accessing database more than needed. My problem is I don't have a fundamental understanding of any of these components, so my question is:

Do I need to use anything else other than FDQuery?

A little more context on what I'm building: UniGUI web application, with the MSSQL server in the same LAN as the Web Server, and multiple user access to DB.

Comment: A memory table is not connected to a server. You populate it manually.

Comment: I've voted to close this q as being off-topic on SO because it is really asking for a tutorial on DB access using FIreDAC and the unrelated TClientDataSet.  TFDQuery and TFDTable basically parallel TQuery and TTable in the original version of Delphi - there where any number of papers and tutorials explaining the differences between them, try googling.  TFDMemTable and TClientDataSets are basically in-memory datasets, again google for explanations of their uses.  TClientDataset was originally designed to be used with TDatasetProvider to [cont]

Comment: ... implement a method (which pre-dates FireDAC) of working with SQL databases which didn't require the server to provide a live, updatable result set and could be used with a "firehose" cursor.  These topics are far too broad to be addressed in a single Q&A which is why your q shoulf be closed.

Comment: I Sugest the book: Delphi/Kylix Dtabase Developement (Eric Harmon). This way you will know better how to use ClientDataSet. Your question is a little off topic, you need tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I understand these components better, I found this [FAQ from Embarcadero's doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/TFDQuery,_TFDStoredProc_and_TFDUpdateSQL_Questions) that explains what I wanted to know.

> **Q1: Can I use TFDQuery and connect it to a dataset provider and retrieve the data in an Embarcadero client dataset?**
>
> A: TFDQuery is a mix of TFDMemTable, TFDTableAdapter and several
> TFDCommand's. So, TFDQuery has everything inside to execute SQL
> commands, send parameter data, receive and store result sets, browse
> result sets and post changes back to a database. There is no reason to
> use TFDQuery + DSP + CDS.
>
> You can use TFDMemTable, TFDTableAdapter and TFDCommand directly,
> instead of TFDQuery. They give more flexibility, but also require more
> coding. Take for example synchronized cached updates across datasets.
>
> In other words, TFDQuery is an optimal "shortcut" for every day data
> application programming.